# Migrating from Jersey to RestEasy

Tags: resteasy, jersey-2.0

I'm working out to migrate from `jersey` to `RestEasy` service.

While migrating i'm trying to find an equivalent method in `RestEasy` for **post** method in `WebResource`.

```
WebResource.post(clazz, data); // Equivalent method of post in RestEasy
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

jax-rs 2.0 (json) way to do this with resteasy is:

**Create a client**

```
final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();
cm.setMaxTotal(200);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

final ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(httpClient);

final Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().httpEngine(engine).register(ResteasyJackson2Provider.class).build();
```

**Create a WebTarget**

```
final ResteasyWebTarget webtarget = (ResteasyWebTarget) client.target(serviceUrl);
```

**Make the POST call to your endpoint**

```
final Response response = webtarget.path("yourEndpointPath>").request().post(Entity.entity(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
```